# Pandas dataframe manipulation to get out periods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[101,102,103],
    'Name':['Axel','Bob','Charles'],
    'Vol Q1':[100,102,104],
    'Vol Q2':[101,103,105],
    'Trans Q1':[1,3,5],
    'Trans Q2':[2,4,6],
 })
```

I want to convert it to the form:

```
df4=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID':[101,101,102,102,103,103],
    'Name':['Axel','Axel','Bob','Bob','Charles','Charles'],
    'Quarter':['Q1','Q2','Q1','Q2','Q1','Q2'],
    'Vol':[100,101,102,103,104,105],
    'Trans':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
 })
```

But I cannot figure out how.

I tried:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df1,id_vars=['ID','Name'])
```

But this does not give the desired format. It puts all of them in one column. And I cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `pd.wide_to_long`

```
pd.wide_to_long(df1, stubnames=['Trans', 'Vol'], sep=' ', suffix='Q\d+', i=['ID', 'Name'], j='Quarter').reset_index()

Out[31]:
    ID     Name Quarter  Trans  Vol
0  101     Axel   Q1      1  100
1  101     Axel   Q2      2  101
2  102      Bob   Q1      3  102
3  102      Bob   Q2      4  103
4  103  Charles   Q1      5  104
5  103  Charles   Q2      6  105
```

Comment: Well done!! (-: